# React is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I just started to play around with the [react gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) but I seem to running into issues. With the code below, whenever I get routed to my react example page, I notice in the browser developer console, it will say "React is not defined." It's referring to this line:

*var react_example = React.createClass({*

which is in the *react_example.js.jsx* file (see below).

**Gemfile**

```
#... as well as other gems...
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'react-rails' #<------ React
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

**development.rb**

```
config.react.variant = :development
config.react.addons = true
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>React example</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "react" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**react_example.js.jsx**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var react_example = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>React</h5>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually not the best way to do it, unless you really wanna load react apart from your application.

The documentation states clearly you should do this inside your application.js manifest file:

```
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
```

The line that mention "components" depends on the folder you actually puts your react component files.

Answer (score 2):

Try switching your JS includes:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "react" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Since you use React in your application JS, it needs to be defined first.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, but now my html is not actually rendering my react component. React is loaded, as well as my script, but nothing is being shown on my page.

Comment: You need a call to `React.renderComponent` or the Rails view helper `render_component` somewhere. See the React tutorial and react-rails README for more details.