# Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am trying to make ReactJS work with rails using [this](http://rny.io/rails/react/2014/07/31/reactjs-and-rails.html) tutorial. I am getting this error:

---

`Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

But I can access the React object in browser console[image]
I also added [public/dist/turbo-react.min.js](https://github.com/ssorallen/turbo-react/blob/master/public/dist/turbo-react.min.js) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851588/how-can-i-use-this-react-library-with-react-rails?answertab=votes#tab-top) and also added `//= require components` line in application.js as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974478/react-is-not-defined?answertab=votes#tab-top) to no luck. Additionally,
`var React = require('react')` gives the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Can anyone suggest me on how to resolve this?

**[EDIT 1]**
Source code for reference:
This is my `comments.js.jsx` file:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
          {this.props.comment}
      </div>
      );
  }
});

var ready = function () {
  React.renderComponent(
    <Comment author="Richard" comment="This is a comment "/>,
    document.getElementById('comments')
  );
};

$(document).ready(ready);
```

And this is my `index.html.erb`:

```
<div id="comments"></div>
```

Comment: For reader in 2021 using Webpack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64994595/5290519

Comment: In my case an import was missing: `import React from 'react'`

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this error when I was using webpack to build my javascript with the following chunk in my `webpack.config.json`:

```
externals: {
    'react': 'React'
},
```

This above configuration tells webpack to not resolve `require('react')` by loading an npm module, but instead to expect a global variable (i.e. on the `window` object) called `React`. The solution is to either remove this piece of configuration (so React will be bundled with your javascript) or load the React framework externally before this file is executed (so that `window.React` exists).

Comment: I don't have that in my configuration

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? it doesn't answer the question. it doesn't answer any questions, just reiterates the problem.

Answer (score 306):

If you are using Babel and React 17, you might need to add "runtime": "automatic" to Babel config.

In `.babelrc` config file this would be:

```
 {
     "presets": [
         "@babel/preset-env",
        ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}]
     ]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. I'm just wondering why it's better than adding react to `externals` or `plugins` using `ProvidePlugin` in the Webpack config?

Comment: This worked for me. Im using rollup and I had to add this to my plugins:              babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                presets: [
                    "@babel/preset-env",
                    ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}],
                ]
            }),

Comment: What config? Where should I add it?

Comment: Good point! this is was for .babelrc file.

Comment: For those who like more explanation: (credit Chat-GPT): 

`@babel/preset-react` is a Babel preset that transforms React JSX syntax to plain JS. Adding `{"runtime": "automatic"}` enables a new JSX transform [introduced in React 17] that uses the React runtime to generate necessary code for JSX expressions. This eliminates the need for React to be in scope and allows for better optimisation, [such as generating less code and reducing total bundle size]. The default classic transform requires the `React` object to be in scope.

Comment: Also, take note: If you are experiencing this issue after bundling your code with Webpack(4). You likely need to add this option to the `@babel/preset-react` preset listed in the Webpack config file under `loader: "babel-loader"`

Comment: @mm_ you could use CRACO if you don't want to eject your app. Just put the settings above (given by @Jkarttunen) in the craco.config.ts file. More more information, see
https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/babel/

Answer (score 117):

I got this error because I was using

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

without importing react, once I changed it to below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

The error was solved :)

Comment: (plus 1) - Makes perfect sense

Comment: Works! That is a bit unexpected coming from a language like Python. If I'm only using `ReactDOM` in my main file, I thought I can (and should) get rid of the reference to `React`. Oh well, learned something.

Comment: with mine React18 I have these imports like:`import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 68):

If you are using Webpack, you can have it load React when needed without having to explicitly `require` it in your code.

Add to **webpack.config.js**:

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "React": "react",
   }),
],
```

See http://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#plugin-provideplugin

Comment: I thought I could do `React: "react"` to be consistent with other `ProvidePlugins`, but no - must be `"React"` quoted.

Comment: That worked for me but I had to swap the case `"react":''React"`

Comment: Very cool, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 43):

Possible reasons are 1. you didn't load React.JS into your page, 2. you loaded it after the above script into your page. Solution is load the JS file before the above shown script.

P.S

Possible solutions.

1. If you mention `react` in externals section inside webpack configuration, then you must load react js files directly into your html before `bundle.js`
2. Make sure you have the line `import React from 'react';`

Answer (score 40):

Try to add:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
window.React = React
```

before the `render()` function.

This sometimes prevents error to pop-up returning:

> React is not defined

Adding `React` to the window will solve these problems.

Comment: The last line was the missing part for me.

Comment: thanks bro! I was trying to find a solution for almost 2 hours! Boom.
The last line fixed it.

Comment: Adding `import React from 'react'` to the main js file was enough in my case.

Answer (score 18):

*Adding to Santosh :*

You can load React by

```
import React from 'react'
```

Comment: @zero_cool I love semi-colons as it makes code easier to read, but they are optional in JavaScript. When omitted, they will be automatically inserted. The official EcmaScript spec has this info: "Moreover, line terminators, although not considered to be tokens, also become part of the stream of input elements and guide the process of automatic semicolon insertion (11.9)." from: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-lexical-and-regexp-grammars which points to this: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion So technically, both of your code examples are correct & valid JS.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is answered. But since what worked for me isn't exactly in the answers, I'll add it here in the hopes that it will be useful for someone else.

My `index.js` file looked like this when I was getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`.

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Adding `import React from 'react';` at the top of the file fixed it.

Now my `index.js` looks like this and I don't get any error on the console.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Please note I made no change in webpack.config.js or anywhere else to make this work.

Comment: If you are using any React version earlier than 17, then importing React into the file is necessary.  17 and after is supposed to no longer require the React import in files which use JSX

Answer (score 5):

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

This may also work!

Comment: This gives me a type error: 
`Module '"react"' has no exported member 'PropTypes'.ts(2305)`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using TypeScript, make sure that your `tsconfig.json` has `"jsx": "react"` within `"compilerOptions"`.

Comment: I has the similar: `"jsx": "react-jsx",`, tried your version with simply 'react' - it doesn't help in both cases..(

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue.
I resolved it by importing `React` and `ReactDOM` like as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error because I used:

```
import React from 'react';
```

while working with React, Typescript and Parcel

Changing it to:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Solved the problem as suggested by https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1199#issuecomment-381817548

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because in my code I misspelled a component definition with lowercase `react.createClass` instead of uppercase `React.createClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the order of import can cause this error, if after you have followed all the steps above and still finds it hard on you, try making sure the `react` import comes first.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
```

before any other important you need to make.

Answer (score 1):

I got this because I wrote

`import react from 'react'`

instead of

`import React from 'react'`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using `CRA` and do not want to run `eject`, then you could install [`CRACO`](https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/babel/) and put the following settings into `craco.config.js` file:

```
export default {
  babel: {
    presets: [
      [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        {
          runtime: "automatic"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
};
```

That should remove the `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined` error.

Answer (score 0):

[The displayed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR3hX.png)

[after that import react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R77KH.png)

[Finally import react-dom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyy0U.png)

if error is react is not define,please add ==>`import React from 'react';`

if error is reactDOM is not define,please add ==>`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

Answer (score 0):

To whom using CRA and ended up to this question, can use `customize-cra` and `react-app-rewired` packages to override babel presets in CRA.
To do this, create a `config-overrides.js` in the root and paste this code snippet in it.

```
const { override, addBabelPreset } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
    addBabelPreset('@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop'),
    addBabelPreset([
        '@babel/preset-react',
        {
            runtime: 'automatic',
            importSource: '@emotion/react',
        },
    ]),
);
```

And update scripts in package.json with the ones below.

```
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
```

```
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using vite and my config file was

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plubins: [react()],
  root: "src",
});
```

I don't know what `plubins` are or what monkey put them in my config file, but changing it to `plugins` fixed the problem. PBMAK.

Answer (score 0):

import React from 'react'

will work if you're using vite. VS code was telling me that importing react wasn't necessary but maybe that is true for other libraries/build tools but for now if you're using vite import and ignore the error it is giving you.

Comment: If VSCode throws an error like that, there's something wrong with your configuration.