# Error: Cannot find module 'react' while loading react node module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, browserify, webpack-2, react-boilerplate

I have a react component which I needed to load as a node module in another webpack2 project. Using babelify I converted the react component code to normal javascript code. Following is config I provided to convert.

```
browserify: {
  dist: {
    options: {
       transform: [['babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}]],
       external: ['react', 'react-dom']
    },        
    src: ['src/index.js'],
    dest: 'dist/comp-babelified.js',
  }
}
```

it successfully converted the code. And I am able to load it into the webpack application. But when the webpack application loaded in browser, getting following error in the browser console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'react'
```

If I remove `external` from browserify options, I am getting following error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

Looks like it basically unable to load the react component.

How to correct this issue?

**Update**: I have gone through [Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070303/uncaught-referenceerror-react-is-not-defined) . I don't have React globally. I am expecting webpack understands `require('react')` which is already available in the node_modules.

Comment: Which module are you talking about when you say you 'have' it? You probably need `babel-preset-react` and `babel-preset-es2015`.

Comment: yes..i have added those...