# using webpack ProvidePlugin in React storybook custom webpack config

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've built a wrapper package for drag and drop in React, and I added `storybook` examples.
Since in my consumer React is exposed globally, i'm not importing `React` explicitly.

In the `storybook` examples I need to supply `React` as part of the custom webpack config, but for some reason it can't resolve `React` and I get a `ReferenceError: React is not defined`

This is the package - https://github.com/fiverr/drag_n_drop_package

And this is the custom webpack config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!raw!sass'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really strange but your storybook `webpack.config.js` is mixing webpack v1/v2. 
Importing webpack as

```
const webpack = require('@kadira/storybook/node_modules/webpack');
```

solves it because it uses the same webpack reference that storybook is using (v1).

Comment: Awesome! The regular build is using webpack 2, while storybook only supports webpack 1

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code in `webpack.config.js` at github:

```
externals: {
  react: 'React'
}
```

It looks as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070303/uncaught-referenceerror-react-is-not-defined). If it needs to load the React lib from external, like CDN. The page has to be sure have a script tag for importing React lib. And make sure this script tag is in front of the `bundle.js` or the file which it generated by webpack, so the Object of React will exist when the following code needs to use React, such as:

```
<script src="./react.js"></script>
<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using externals in my consumer as it's already exposed globally, but in storybook I need to resolve the modules on build time. Anyway, @enapupe found my bug, but hanks for trying, I appreciate it :-)