# ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After surfing the forums , I reconfirmed the usage of proper imports as mentioned below:

```
import React from 'react';   
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Also tried removing the following lines from `webpack.config.js`:

```
externals: [           
  {  react: 'React',},         
],
```

But still am getting the following error, while running jest testcases

> ReferenceError: React is not defined

Comment: Why are you importing React with template literal `import React from 'react';` ?? Why are you importing React multiple times? Have you installed React? Please provide your component code otherwise it’s not easy to help you with the solution

Comment: What does your  `package.json` look like?

Comment: @HemadriDasari import React from 'react' ,  will load react

Comment: The webpack instruction `react: 'React'` may confuse and affect such error. If react is not installed nor allowed will be another erorr. `React is not defined` mean thar import module is resolved but it exports does not contain default value which wants as `React` variable.

Comment: Are you using Jest with webpack?

Comment: @oklas I agree . Thus I tried removing the statement but it earned no use for me here .

Comment: @Aadi Yeah . Am using Jest with webpack

Comment: Did you check webpack conf (and all includes) and restart webpack devserver?

Comment: yeah @oklas . I did .

Comment: Are you having a Jest config of sorts. If so can you post it's configuration

Comment: Check manually what is `node_modules/react` exports looks like. May be some error during installation and you have empty file. Also `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` helps in such cases.

Comment: @oklas Tried rm -rf node_modules && npm install already !

Comment: Did you use a git Coud you rollback to stable version? Check also `.babelrc` about react. (Also Post jest config as @Aadi requested let him to see.) Most probably we need manual access to project.

Comment: I have contact at my profile page if any.

Comment: @oklas Thanks . Will contact  if i am not really able to solve it in few more hours .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070303/uncaught-referenceerror-react-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

For jest + react change to `import * as React from 'react'`