# React is undefined, and I have an error connection

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
 const { createElement} = React
 const { render } = ReactDOM

const title = createElement(
'h1',
{id: 'title', className: 'header'},
'Hello World'
 )

render(
title,
document.getElementById('react-container')
 )
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <script src="https://facebook.com/react-15.1.0.js"></script>
      <script src="https://facebook.com/react-dom-15.1.0.js"></script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Hello World with React</title>
      </head>
    <body>
    <div id = "react-container"></div>
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I enter in my code, the local host:3000 server will not load. It says that React is undefined. [Here is what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmcRI.png) Do I need to install something? I have node.js installed, and was working with it so I'm a bit confused. Thank you!

P.S - I used fb.me in the original script, but had to change it to facebook.com.

Comment: Please look the below solution maybe it will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070303/uncaught-referenceerror-react-is-not-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like those `*.js` links are either broken or invalid.

1. https://facebook.com/react-15.1.0.js
2. https://facebook.com/react-dom-15.1.0.js

You can use other CDNs (such as [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/react@16.5.2/) or cloudflare)  as shown below.  (same code as yours except script tags)

*You can run the code below*

```js
 const { createElement} = React
 const { render } = ReactDOM

const title = createElement(
'h1',
{id: 'title', className: 'header'},
'Hello World'
 )

render(
title,
document.getElementById('react-container')
 )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Hello World with React</title>
      </head>
    <body>
    <div id = "react-container"></div>
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```