# Updating JSX transform breaks React

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to upgrade to React 17 and use [the new JSX Transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) to avoid `import React from 'react'`. When I remove `import React` from a component, the page crashes with an error (only when rendering that component).

> React is not defined

I thought I could solve this by [changing my webpack config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64994595/2908576):

```json
// module > rules > use > options > presets
{
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }]
  ]
}
```

(It had previously only been `'@babel/preset-react'` without the options.)

After compiling, I am presented with several errors in the console:

> Warning: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component.
>
> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>
> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render').
>
> Uncaught Error:
> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

The app loads more or less okay until it gets to the React-Table, and then won't go any further after the invalid hook call error.

I've updated some packages to ensure they should be on the correct version:

```json
{
  "@babel/core": "7.16.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "7.16.4",
  "@babel/preset-react": "7.16.0",
  "babel-loader": "8.2.3",
}
```

Any idea why adding `{ runtime: 'automatic' }` messes up how React is operating?

Comment: Is the `React` import used for anything other than `createElement` (e.g. `React.useState` - _"we would still need to import React in order to use Hooks or other exports that React provides"_)? Give a [mre].

Comment: Yes, I also have `import { useState, etc } from 'react'`, but I see this error even if I restore `import React`. Basically, the only change I make is to add `{ runtime: 'automatic' }`, and everything 'splodes.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issues while trying to adopt `JSX Transform`.
I would point out two issues you might be having here.

1. Once you upgrade your React version to `17/ 16.14.x` you need to do a `npm/yarn clean` and **reinstall all your dependencies** and restart the server. And you have to do this everytime you switch between React <16.x and React 17 branches.
2. The `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component` that you're getting is not related to any of your changes. Maybe you've mistakenly called a hook outside of a functional component,you can check your code for that.Once this is fixed, JSX Transform will work as smooth as butter!!