# webpack: ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Got this when loading  a component: `ReferenceError: React is not defined`

Tried this solution here: [Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070303/uncaught-referenceerror-react-is-not-defined)

added following to `webpack.config.json`

```
externals: {'react': 'React' },
```

but then I got following error. So what is wrong?

```
external "React":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at 63804 (external "React":1:18)
    at n (bootstrap:19:32)
    at shortcode32.js?ver=2.0.37:2:317202
    at shortcode32.js?ver=2.0.37:2:385167
```

What files / code should I show to provide you with more info?

---

Error is raised here:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:194 ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at R (LoginAndRegistrationL.tsx:2:2)
    at Yi (react-dom.production.min.js:145:98)
```

in `LoginAndRegistrationL.tsx` funny, I removed everything from `LoginAndRegistrationL.tsx`, only a raw componenet I left:

```
export default function LoginAndRegistrationL(props: {}) {
    return <div></div>
}
```

Why it raise the error?

This componenet will be visible when a button press happens. Why other component does not raise "React" error, but this yes.

Comment: did you try adding  `externals: {
    'react': 'React'
},` in **webpack.config.json**

Comment: yes, I tried it

Comment: I do not know it matters, but prettier chenges key from `'react'` to `react`. And I also tried change value from `'React'` to `'react'`. Did not help.

Comment: import React from 'react';
check you imported react or not

Comment: and if you are using babel then 

 {
     "presets": [
         "@babel/preset-env",
        ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}]
     ]
 }

Comment: @RohitRana I am not sure I am using babel or not. babel lines are in package.json, but 'before' this error was not raised. This babel setting need to add for certain file type?