# Webpack issue where var react (lowercase) but React.createElement (uppercase)

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I webpack (without minimization) the default React application, the bundle.js does not load because React is not defined.  The line fails is:

```
function App_App() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", {
    className: "App"
```

If fails because the variable is react not React.  After find/replace, bundle.js loads correctly.

```
// EXTERNAL MODULE: ./node_modules/react/index.js
var react = __webpack_require__(294);
```

How to configure webpack so that it generates the code correctly?

How to recreate:

```
npx create-react-app w && cd w
npm i -D @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader css-loader html-webpack-plugin sass sass-loader style-loader url-loader webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server
cp ./public/* ./src
```

Create .babelrc and webpack.config.js, then run

```
npx webpack --mode production
```

Open /dist/index.html in the browser, get a blank screen.

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"), // the bundle output path
    filename: "bundle.js", // the name of the bundle
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html", // to import index.html file inside index.js
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    port: 3030, // you can change the port
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, // .js and .jsx files
        exclude: /node_modules/, // excluding the node_modules folder
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/, // styles files
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, // to import images and fonts
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: { limit: false },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "man",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "sass": "^1.69.3",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

OS/node/webpack versions

```
$ npx webpack --version

  System:
    OS: Linux 5.10 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz
    Memory: 1.90 GB / 3.75 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.20.2 - /usr/bin/node
    npm: 8.19.4 - /usr/bin/npm
  Packages:
    babel-loader: ^9.1.3 => 9.1.3
    css-loader: ^6.8.1 => 6.8.1
    html-webpack-plugin: ^5.5.3 => 5.5.3
    sass-loader: ^13.3.2 => 13.3.2
    style-loader: ^3.3.3 => 3.3.3
    url-loader: ^4.1.1 => 4.1.1
    webpack: ^5.88.2 => 5.88.2
    webpack-cli: ^5.1.4 => 5.1.4
    webpack-dev-server: ^4.15.1 => 4.15.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
[Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070303/uncaught-referenceerror-react-is-not-defined)

changed .babelrc to

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    ["@babel/preset-react", {"runtime": "automatic"}]
  ]
}
```